# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'waitpid'

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cygwin, google-search-console

I am trying to install Python2.7.5 on windows using CYGWIN. I am getting the following error when I tried running the `make`

```
running build
running build_ext
ldd: /lib/libreadline.a: Permission denied
building '_struct' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/include -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Include -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5 -c /cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Modules/_struct.c -o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.24-i686-2.7/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Modules/_struct.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 2187, in <module>
    main()
  File "./setup.py", line 2182, in main
    'Lib/smtpd.py']
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "./setup.py", line 251, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "./setup.py", line 289, in build_extension
    build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 875, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/spawn.py", line 34, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Venkateshwaran/Downloads/Python-2.7.5.tar/Python-2.7.5/Lib/distutils/spawn.py", line 148, in _spawn_posix
    pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'waitpid'
Makefile:471: recipe for target `sharedmods' failed
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

Previously I executed ./configure file and it was successful.